# Android studio first run stuck at "Downloading Components" window

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded the latest android studio bundle from android site. Installation was successful, but when I run it for the first time, it shows a window in the screenshot with message "Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 24.1.2" and then it hangs on infinitely. 
When I click on cancel and then show details, the message in attached screenshot appears. This dialog never disappears even on clicking the close button. I have to end it from process manager.
I was wondering if anyone has been able to make it work.
[image]

Comment: You sure it isn't just downloading it?

Comment: Its just stuck at progress bar progress you can see in picture. And also I have downloaded the sdk bundle (around 800MB) so it should have the sdk Tools "bundled" in it. I don't see any reason that it should download anything after that. @TameHog

Comment: Even the SDK manager has a problem showing download progress...https://ibb.co/nqYBQ7

Answer (score 21):

To disable "Downloading Components" at startup,

- Go to the installation directory of Android Studio.
- There you    will find a folder named "bin".
- Inside this folder there is a file    named "idea.properties".
- Open this file and add the following    line to the end of the file:

  `disable.android.first.run=true`

What this will do is disable the check that Android Studio performs on first run and decides to download all that stuff.

If it asks to save the file at some different place instead of overwriting the original one, please check the access permissions to the file.

Comment: This immediately fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you got stuck earlier and left in middle of download, this may happen

Just go to

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android

and delete the SDK folder and now try again.

Answer (score 3):

To me it has worked perfectly. You have to download all data for the sdk and can be several GB and can take a long time depending on connection and repositories

Comment: My SDK bundle I downloaded was about 836,166 KB. Its name is android-studio-bundle-135.1740770-windows.exe so it should be complete bundle.

Comment: After that, when you run first time the application, Android studio download  much data after that, like system image for emulators for each sdk version, sdks for older versions, sdk documentation, etc. My sdk folder occupy 34GB

Comment: If that is so, then its RIDICULOUS!! There must be some way to just download a minimal set of data which should make me start developing quickly. 34 GB of data would take around 2-3 days to download with internet connections in india.

Comment: Yep its not necessary all sdk data for start working,only the version that is going to be your target.If you open the sdk manager from Android studio or from the sdk folder (its a java app) you can choose which data you want to download. I dont know what data its downloading from this window

Comment: Go to sdk manager and choose what you want to download (last sdk), and start Android Studio again and see what happens.

Comment: Download at least last SDKTools and one sdk.

Comment: I have all the SDK ready. I currently develop android apps with intellij idea. But wanted to switch to android studio.

Comment: Then you dont need  download, only the android plugin studio  SDK tools for this. And configure your SDK path for avoiding automatic download

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I would try in some time and get back to you. I have already upvoted for your answer.

Comment: thanks for the vote, i hope i helped you,if you make any progress, tell me

Comment: Mine took 25 minutes at 15 MBPS download speed, before any changes to the progress bar or log messages occurred. Thanks for your post, it convinced me to wait.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a bug with the Setup Wizard. See more [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82152)

You could try to download the previous [stable](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable) release: 1.0.2 or 1.0.1.

**EDIT**

After further testing, apparently if you force close `adb` the wizard continues normally.

Answer (score 2):

It will take some time to install. Hence do not cancel the process. In my case it took 20 to 30 minutes

If you already canceled the process then you can delete the android sdk and re-run.

Answer (score 1):

it is a reported bug and I am facing it too in version 1.2.0 see [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82152) 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Components of the SDK are continuously released and Android Studio's updates aren't very frequent.
You can update the components manually with SDK Manager.

1. Go to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
2. Open SDK Manager.exe
3. Update the packages.
4. Start Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

its not stuck. its actually downloading some tools. 
if we download like this or through SDK manager.exe the speed is limited.
so it will take much time.
so i tried to open it without internet connection and it showed me some missing tools.
(andoid sdk tool 21.1.1 )
i had 21.1.2 installed but it still showed this. so i manually downloaded it from
internet ( here you will get your max download speed). and placed it with 21.1.2 installation file.
and now it all works.

ps:it was the only file i missed. it won't be the same with everyone