# Stuck at Downloading Components (Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.4.5)" android studio

Tags: android, components

Hello Guys I just want some help for installing android studio components, I already installed the android studio but when I downloading the components on first startup of the application, It stuck at downloading component (image attached below). I have a fast internet connections but It doesn't continue.
Thank you guys

[image: Stuck at Downloading]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but after reading several posts it appeared that for some users it just takes a long time for the first download to complete during which it does not show any progress. So by just leaving it for about 10min+ it might carry on.

Having said that, in my attempts to get it going I did the following (although I now believe none of it might have been necessary)

1. remove the original installation by deleting /Program Files/android
2. remove the SDK files by deleting \Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android
3. install latest version of Java
4. restart computer
5. - i wanted to install chipmunk but at this point I installed bumblebee from the self install exe
6. start android studio - the setup wizard starts AND gets stuck for about 10 minutes!!
7. Let it complete its download and select finish
8. at this point I copied / started Chipmunk and this time it had no problem with setup wizard.

If this does not work, also see a similar link below:
[android-studio-first-run-stuck-at-downloading-components-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298638/android-studio-first-run-stuck-at-downloading-components-window)

Comment: The link just links back to this post.

Comment: @Donald Duck - Thank you, I must have pasted the wrong link at the time.