# Mac silicon android studio installation stuck on downloading

Tags: macos, android-studio

So i've downloaded the correct apple silicon android studio installation from their website. when trying to install the installation process gets stuck on this message:

> Downloading
> https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip
> Warning: This download could not be finalized from the interim state.
> Retrying without caching. Downloading
> https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip

I have left it like that for hours but with no luck

any workaround?

Comment: Here's a related thread with more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366800/cannot-install-android-emulator-via-android-studio-in-macbook-m1-pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by Google via this bug ticket:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242575308#comment27

> Verified by bo...@google.com.
>
> hello,
> thanks a lot for reporting the problem.
> please try to download emulator 31.3.10 again on M1, and it should work now, but report problems if you run into.
>
> thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 4):

today I solved the problem like this:

1. Download file and unzip: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip
2. Cancel button.
3. Go to /Users/YOUR NAME/Library/Android/sdk
4. Delete the folder "emulator" and add new unzipped folder the same name
5. Finish!

Try to add simulator.

Later, maybe I will find a better way, but this way allowed me to work at the moment and not delay work.

Comment: thanks for the reply! the thing Is, I don't need the emulator. the initial android studio installation does not continue because of this. I tired putting the emulator folder in there but when I try to reinstall android studio all it does is skip this folder and create a new one with a different name and then gets stuck again

Comment: Hello, try to upload now, it seems Google has solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

@TomerZigdon Do you actually need an emulator for testing?

Here's a solution that worked for me. I have a physical device that I test the apps on and I don't require an emulator. So as per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880185/3273842), I disabled android checking for first run. Android Studio opens just usual and on creating a new (dummy) project, it installs the needed SDK versions (not the emulator)

`disable.android.first.run=true`

Full credits & steps to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880185/3273842

Comment: thanks for your reply!
I don't have an installation folder yet because it gets stuck before installing anything. in the android folder it created I can't see any bin folder..